# react: array "contains" method

Tags: javascript, react-redux

I have a react class component, which has in its state a parameter object of type "credentials" :

{ user: '' , password: '' }.

I add new "credentials" to a "credentialList" array also in the state and output it. I am trying to make the program give me an error when I try to enter a new "credentials" with a user that already exists in the list. I gave each "credentials" a key value equal to user. Unfortunately this has not worked. I marked the problematic if statement in ** **. Thanks to any helper. My code:

```
state = {
    user: '',
    password: '',
    clicked: false,
    credentialsList: []
}

userChangedHandler = (event) => {
    this.setState( { user: event.target.value })
}

passwordChangedHandler = (event) => {
    this.setState( { password: event.target.value })
}

userSubmitHandler = () => {
    if(this.state.user === '' || this.state.password === ''){
        alert('Please enter username and password!');
    }
    const credential = {user: this.state.user , password: this.state.password};
    **if(this.state.credentialsList.length !== 0 && this.state.credentialsList.contains(credential)){
        alert('Enter New')
    }**
    else {
        let newList = [...this.state.credentialsList, {user: this.state.user, password: this.state.password }];
        this.setState({clicked: true, user: '', password: '', credentialsList: newList})
    }
}

formEraseHandler = () => {
    if(this.state.credentialsList.length === 0){
        alert('The User List is Empty!')
    }
    else {
        let newList = [];
        this.setState({ credentialsList: newList, user:'', password:''});
    }
}

render() {
    return(
     <div>
        <Form
            credentialsList={this.state.credentialsList}
            user={this.state.user}
            password={this.state.password}
            clicked={this.state.clicked}
            userChanged={(event) => this.userChangedHandler(event)}
            passwordChanged={(event) => this.passwordChangedHandler(event)}
            addButtonClicked={this.userSubmitHandler}
            resetButtonClicked={this.formEraseHandler}/>
        <CredentialsList credentials={this.state.credentialsList}/>
     </div>
    )
}
```

}

Comment: You cant compare objects with a simple ==, that contains will be doing.  Try using Array.find or simiair.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is no `contains` method but you can use [`some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)

Here is an example:

```
const exists = this.state.credentialsList.some(v => (v.user === credential.user && v.password === credential.password));
```

The code above checks if any of the objects inside the `credentialsList` array has the same `user` and `password` properties values as the `credential` object. You can modify the `if` condition if you don't want to check for both these properties.

Answer (score 6):

I think the method you are looking for is [includes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes)

This will compare the entire object with the one given in params. For example:

```
const credentials = [{ username: 'foo', password: 'bar' }];
credentials.includes({ username: 'foo, password: 'bar' }); // true
credentials.includes({ username: 'foo, password: 'foobar' }); // false
```

If you want to compare specific values then the  [some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) method is more 
appropriate

```
credentials.some(cred => cred.username === this.state.username); // true
```